# Cannot access FreeNAS share from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, samba, freenas

Just set up FreeNAS 11.2.U7. After installation, I created a group (ShareUsers) and a user (MyUser). I checked the 'Microsoft Account' checkbox.

I created a pool MyPool and a dataset MyDataset, for which I set the permissions to Windows, Apply User, MyUser, group ShareUsers.

Then I created an SMB share for /mnt/MyPool/MyDataset, and was asked to start the SMB service (which I did).

From my Windows 7 machine I try to access the share. If I navigate to the IP address of FreeNAS, I can see the share, but when I double click it I always get "access denied". When I try the same from a command prompt (net use w: \IP\Share), this works, but when I navigate to w: I get access denied again.

I've looked at about 10 tutorials online which basically all tell me the same procedure as I've done above, and I've read countless times how easy setting up a share should be, but still I cannot access the share.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for all suggestions!

Edit: I've tried allowing guest access, but that doesn't change a thing.

Comment: What version of SMB are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea what version of SMB FreeNAS is using... Where can I check this?

Comment: @Ramhound I've found a mention online of a "tunable" called freenas.services.smb.config.server_min_protocol . Apparently it should be set to NT1, but I've tried adding this and it didn't work (so I disabled it again).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the wrong user-account to connect to the NAS.
It expects the newly created account "MyUser" but your Windows 7 install will try to connect with whatever user-account you happen to be logged in to Windows 7.
You Windows 7 has no idea about "MyUser".

Try to do a "Connect as different user" to the share and specify the user account explicitly. Or on the `net use` command use the `/user` parameter to specify the account.

Comment: Thanks Tonny, but I've tried that already. When I open Windows Eplorer and double click on the share, I never get the option of entering a username or password, it immediately says access denied. When I try "connect as different user" and enter MyUser and password, it fails as well. Doing it from the command prompt with the option /user didn't work either.

Comment: @Marlon The behavior you describe is still consistent with using the wrong user-account. Dit you prefix the userid with the domain (which would be the hostname of the NAS)? Like "NASNAME\MyUser"

Comment: Tonny, I did - I tried /user:MyUser as well as /user:\\freenas\MyUser . Both gave me the access denied error.

Comment: The last version isn’t right. There shouldn’t be any backslashes before the server name

Comment: Tonny, my mistake. I tried with /user:freenas\MyUser, but still I get the access denied error.